# Project running in eclipse but not in netbeans

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, jsp, netbeans

I'm trying to build a RESTful Web Service, in which I have made a dynamic web project named RESTFulWebServer which contains the basic HTTP GET PUT POST requests. And a dynamic web project named ClientProject which contains a simple jsp page containing javascript. The ClientProject's javascript is supposed to make a call to the RESTFulWebServer's java page named MyUserClass and print output in console.

When I ran these projects in Eclipse, they worked like a charm. The call was made, and the MyUserClass's GET method was called perfectly and it displayed the output on console (as was desired)

However now I have to shift to NetBeans for some very important reason, and now that I have imported both my projects in NetBeans, and executed them, the call from ClientProject's javascript is not being made to the RESTFulWebServer's java page. The strangest thing is that when I run RESTFulWebServer project the output is shown on the console. But when I run the ClientProject it is supposed to print one line on console(i.e output window) as well, but here it doesn't

How come it can work perfectly in Eclipse but not in NetBeans? (Also I'm making use of Tomcat server)

I'm stuck . Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated!

(Attaching both the project's codes below:)

This is the ClientProject's jsp page named clientfile.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Update User</title>
<script>
function loadResponse()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("DELETE","http://localhost:8080/app/user/service",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">The response text would come here</div>
<button type ="button" onclick="loadResponse()">submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is now the MyUserClass.java code from RESTfulWebServer project

```
package com.service.user;
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/user/service")
public class UserServices {
    @PUT
    @Path("/create")
    public void createUser()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside create user method");
    }

    @GET
    public void getUser()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside get user method");
    }

    @POST
    public void updateUser()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside update user method");
    }

    @DELETE
    public void deleteUser()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside DELETE user method");
    }
}
```

Comment: Main problem is that eclipse web project have slightly different folder structure and project description files and how eclipse configure project  environment (like classpath, server configuration files,  how to start webserver and where webserver config files located). Create netbeans web project and move file to appropriate folders. But best is convert project to maven webapp project, since it has unified folder structure and u can shift easily to any your favorite IDE later.

Comment: Isn't there any other way around? Because I have to incorporate this stuff in another project which is quite large already.
Also are you sure I'm not making any mistake in the code? :/ I'm new to javascript and don't know almost anything really

Comment: There is in netbeans File->Import->Eclipse Project. This is simplest way to import project.